# How to create belongToMany with some fields?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Help pls.
I don't understand. How to add fields to a relationship belongsToMany Laravel nova.
Version Nova - 3.27 (last for today).Fields even without an example with pivot.
Example and Example2 fields show only Edit page. View and Index! doesn't show.

```
BelongsToMany::make('Product in cart', 'productPrices', ProductPrice::class)->fields(function () {
            return [
                Text::make('Example')->showOnIndex(true),
            Text::make('Example2')->showOnIndex(true)->displayUsing(function($field) {}),
            ];
        }),
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for the pivot fields to show up on the `Detail` page of your resource, the `BelongsToMany` fields have to be defined on **both** Resources. You should add the inverse of the relationship as a `BelongsToMany` as well to `ProductPrice` Nova Resource.

The `BelongsToMany` fields never show on `Index` pages however. But there is a fix for that, you could create a field that is only present on index like so:

```
Textarea::make('Products in cart', function () {
    return $this->productPrices->map(function ($productPrice) {
      // build a correct string here
      return sprintf("%s - %s <br/>", $productPrice->name, $productPrice->amount); 
    })->join('');
})->onlyOnIndex();
```

The above code might have to be adjusted to suit your needs. But it will only show up on the index page.